# Is it appropriate to scale ML output using function? (distortion?)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, regression

I am training a neural network using tensorflow (sigmoid function).

I want to scale my data (output y in a regressional setup) between 0 and 1. Is it appropriate to do this using a function? E.g. `y_train = log(y)`?
My concern is that it will distort the data.

I am a bit unsure about using the usual scaling methods that are based on the sample (e.g. rescaling:`(y-ymin)/y_range` or standardization) as I do not the actual range of y, and the range of y values in my validation set might be quite different from the range in my training set if I do it this way.

What is the proper way to scale my data between 0-1 in this situation?

Comment: The motivation for doing this is that the neural network has a sigmoid at the end, and so its output range is (0, 1), right? Can you simply remove the sigmoid from your model? That way, you don't have to change your training data, the final layer should learn to "aim" for the correct range.

Comment: If you are using a sigmoid output layer, then your data will be in (0,1). No need to scale.